# The path to save a text file resulting from an app written with swift on iphone

Tags: swift

I have an app (written with swift) which runs on iphone 6. I need to save some text resulting from the app, into a file. What should be the path for this file?

Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many places to save such a file. It's common to save your documents in the **Documents** folder for your app.

This is how you can get the NSUrl for documents folder:

```
 let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first
```

Comment: I did not know there is a Documents folder on my iPhone. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, this is unique for your app, no other app has access to this. You can allow access to users to grab files when they connect their phone to iTunes but it's disabled by default.

Comment: what is the difference between the address you have provided and NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory

Comment: **NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory** is NOT a string, it's an enum. if you look at the code in the answer, we're using the very same enum to get the NSUrl to DocumentDirectory so they're about the same directory, one os the url to it, the other one is an enum representing it. does it make sense?